# Can I assign custom keyboard shortcuts to custom (non-default) unity lenses?

Tags: unity, shortcut-keys, lenses

I installed the recoller lense ( http://www.webupd8.org/2012/03/recoll-lens-full-text-search-unity-lens.html ) and now finally have fulltext search in dash.

File lense is opened with super+F, music with super+M and so on. Can (and how can ) I assing such a shortuct to this new lense?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It appears that lens package is installing using a pre-existing shortcut, `a`, why I don't know. (a bug should be filed, at least for 12.04

To check & edit, make sure you use something not in use, here I used `l`

```
sudo -H gedit /usr/share/unity/lenses/recoll/recoll.lens
```

change `Shortcut=a` to a letter of your choice

Noting again that this is what I found on 12.04

Comment: I think it comes from copying application lense and then editing it to make recoller lense. Bug filled: https://bitbucket.org/medoc/recoll/issue/86/unity-lense-uses-existing-shortcus - it also applies to 11.10

Comment: I talked to the dev, he's going to leave the line blank. It would then be up to users to set an appropriate one for themselves. A logical one would be `r` but that currently taken by the ezoom plugin & causing a whole lot of trouble for unsuspecting users

Comment: In 12.04 super+r has now been freed up so could be used for recoll

Comment: Note to users using this (excellent) answer: You may need to either run `unity --replace` or logout/login to make the bindings be changed